# Isn't PHP's null value equal to MySQL's null value?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a variable on php and it sometimes can be `NULL` and I want to insert this variable to my db. But problem is, PHP's null value does not insert to db as null value.

My column on db allows null values.

```
if($variable != true){
   $variable = null;
}

//insert my null value to db

$insert = $db->prepare("insert into mytable set mycolumn = $variable" );
$insert->execute();

//mycolumn is an integer column which is DEFAULT null

//above query fails. Why?
```

Comment: is this your actual code? If so, you're missing a closing quote.

Comment: i missed it while writing my question here. I have a closing quoute on my code.

Comment: NULL values are not considered equal in MySQL. Plus, in your example, `$variable` is converted to an empty string => SQL error. You should be using prepared statements.

Comment: As for _Isn't PHP's null value equal to MySQL's null value?_ The answer is NO.

Comment: no. php null in a string context becomes an empty string. you're doing `set mycolumn = ;`, with no value. if you want a php null to become an sql null, you have to `if ($var === null) { $var = 'null'; }` convert it to a STRING with the chars `n`, `u`, `l`, `l`

Comment: Use the real code,this is not how prepare works

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314353/set-value-to-null-in-mysql

Comment: Using PDO, bind the parameter and set the type to `PDO::PARAM_NULL` should do the trick : http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php - so while PHP's `null` is not necessarily the same as MySQLs you can use it to ensure you're inserting `NULL` into the DB when your PHP value is `null`

Comment: this question actually an answer for my question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4620409/1848929

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because PHP `null` is converted into the empty string "" when you create the query string.

```
$variable = null;
$insert = "insert into mytable set mycolumn = $variable" ;
echo $insert;
```

Will produce:

```
insert into mytable set mycolumn =
```

To fix your query you would need to check if the PHP variable is null and change it to string NULL. (Also now mentioned in the comment of @MarkB.)

```
if ($variable == null){
    $variable = "NULL";
}
```

This will produce:

```
"insert into mytable set mycolumn = NULL"
```

**Note that NULL has no " around it because it is now concatenated to the other string.**

---

*(*note: `insert into tablename set ..` is not correct, you either `insert` data or you `update tablename set` data.)*

Comment: This is the answer for my question, but if null is a string on mysql why i'm using  `.. SET column = null ` instead of `.. SET column= "null" ` on my mysql editor?

Comment: `$insert = "insert into mytable set mycolumn = $variable" ;` with $variable set to "null" will produce that as well.

Comment: The problem here is conversion from php to mysql, you need to provide the query as a string that is why it has ", when you concatenate the strings the " from the variable are gone.

Answer (score 2):

(Not an answer to your actual question but maybe to your problem. The "immediate" problem regarding the [variable substitution](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) in your double-quoted string has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33809490/4833))

Since you're already using [prepare](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) you can simply make it a parametrized statement

```
$insert = $db->prepare('insert into mytable set mycolumn=?' );
$insert->execute( array($variable) );
```

and $variable===NULL will result in a NULL value in your MySQL table.

e.g.

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly', array(
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY=>false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));
setup($pdo);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO soFoo SET mycolumn=?');

$variable = 1;    $stmt->execute( array($variable) );
$variable = NULL; $stmt->execute( array($variable) );
$variable = 2;    $stmt->execute( array($variable) );

foreach( $pdo->query('SELECT id,mycolumn FROM soFoo', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    var_export($row);
}

function setup($pdo) {
    $pdo->exec('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soFoo (
            id int auto_increment,
            mycolumn int,
            primary key(id) 
        )
    ');
}
```

prints

```
array (
  'id' => 1,
  'mycolumn' => 1,
)array (
  'id' => 2,
  'mycolumn' => NULL,
)array (
  'id' => 3,
  'mycolumn' => 2,
)
```