# SQL UPDATE value as null or string

Tags: php, sql

I searched almost whole internet, but could not find something similar, yet my question looks so simple.

I have a php code like so:

```
$id = 1;    
if (!isset($_POST['port1'])) {
        $port1 = null;
    }
```

... which simply checks if submitted value is empty or not, if it is empty, then variable `$port1 = null;`

then, further in the code, I need to insert this value/update it in the database

```
$sql_update = ("UPDATE names_10 SET `digName1`=$port1 WHERE `device_id`='$id'");
```

...which should set the "digname1" to null. but it won't!
I tried every combination, every type of quotes, but every time I got UPDATE error..

any ideas?

Comment: `null` in a string in php is not the same as `NULL` as a value in a query.  I think you should solve this by using parameters rather than munging the string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314353/set-value-to-null-in-mysql

Comment: @GordonLinoff What do you mean by "using parameters"? I need to use this variable

Comment: @SahilGulati no, this will insert null as string

Comment: update your error

Comment: @BunkerBoy What? Update my error? What error?

Comment: why don't you use PDO or at least something with bindings?

Comment: what type of error are you getting would please show us ?

Comment: @AlexSlipknot i didn't heard about that... kinda beginner in php

Comment: @BunkerBoy not that easy... it is made with AJAX request on other site So it Only echos the text error... which happens If there was error in SQL update... But Okay, i will find the error and Edit my question

Comment: Here is an example how to use PDO: http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/insert-update-and-delete-with-pdo/

Comment: @AlexSlipknot Thanks, i will take a look

Comment: @Alex Slipknot let him start without pdo as he said he is beginner in php

Comment: @Bunker Boy let it be, but at least there is must be injection-protection!

Comment: @AlexSlipknot there is, this is Only the important part of code.. injection solving things does not matter in this question.. don't worry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$id = 1;    
if (!isset($_POST['port1'])) {
        $port1 = "NULL";
}

$sql_update = ("UPDATE names_10 SET `digName1`= $port1 WHERE `device_id`='$id'");
```

I would rather suggest you to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) when you plan to bind something like this. There are a lot of benefits using PDO that would amaze you!

Comment: Okay, i will read about it. And try What? Looks identical to my code ...

Comment: case sensitive 'NULL' (that is string and not NULL)

Comment: Okay, i will try

Comment: Do you want null as a string in your database?

Comment: @SatishSaini boom, after you updated the answer i tried... Now it works!!!!!! Thanks!!!!

Comment: @DavidStančík Cool :) Glad that it worked for you! :)

Comment: @SatishSaini Thanks a lot! :-)